# Visual Studio Variable Errors

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering why I keep getting the following error for this visual script. I checked my code and it all seems to look fine. Why can't the function be called here?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub BtnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnStart.Click
    MsgBox("Hello World")
    MsgBox("Hello World!")
    MsgBox("Hello?")
End Sub
End Class
```

BC30506: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

its saying I need events for calling the handler, but I already have the MsgBox text appearing. Also it seems to have trouble registering the button click, is there any other way to write this?

Comment: Is this possibly VB.NET, and not C++?

Comment: This isn't C++.

Comment: When you look at the button's events in the designer, is BtnStart_Click still associated with the BtnStart.Click event?

Comment: *"its saying I need events for calling the handler"*. No, it's saying that you need a variable to be declared `WithEvents` in order for it to be included in the `Handles` clause of a method. Do you have such a variable? The error message indicates not. Please post the contents of your designer code file, where such a variable would be declared. You will need to click the *Show All Files* button in the *Solution Explorer* and then expand the node for your form in order to see it.

Comment: If you have such a variable then something is going wrong with VS and the first thing I'd do is delete that method, then delete the `Button`, then restart VS (and possibly Windows) and then add a new `Button` and double-click it to generate a `Click` event handler. Hopefully that will right whatever is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It not clear what is not working here?

the desginer should look like this, and MAKE SURE you bring up the property sheet, and check and double check that the click event is setup for that button.

eg this:

[image]

So, as above shows, the click event has a code behind stub setting.

So, in code, then we should see/find this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    MsgBox("my button 2 click")

End Sub
```

So, your code looks fine, but it is possible that the client event of the button is not setup. Take a look at the property sheet for that button, and select the "events" tab in the property sheet as I done above.

Make sure the name for the click event matches the code behind stub.

So, in above, we see "Button2_Click".

So, our code behind then has to 100% match that like this:

[image]

So note how the "highlighted" Button2_Click in the click event has to be 100% the same. So, bring up the property sheet for that button in the designer. Then select events (the lighting bolt), and verify that the click event is set, and that it matches the signature of your code behind click event.